# How to get data from RDS postgresql to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to get all records from a RDS postgresql in AWS and load than in a S3 bucket as csv file.

The script i am using is:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node JDBC Connection
JDBCConnection_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="core",
    table_name="core_public_table",
    transformation_ctx="JDBCConnection_node1",
)

# Script generated for node ApplyMapping
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=JDBCConnection_node1,
    mappings=[
        ("sentiment", "string", "sentiment", "string"),
        ("scheduling", "long", "scheduling", "long"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
)

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=ApplyMapping_node2,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={"path": "s3://path_to_s3", "partitionKeys": []},
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3",
)

job.commit()
```

But this job is failing due to `An error occurred while calling getDynamicFrame`

I read every post about in stackoverflow but I can't solve it.  Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Rds [natively supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html) exporting to s3. Don't need glue job for that.

Comment: I only have access to RDS postgresql using Glue due to company's rules..